# Как нарисовать круг в круге с помощью кода

Tags: ios, swift

Хочу нарисовать круг в круге. Получается внешний белый и внутри него синий, размеры всё четко указал, расположение что на чём лежит тоже, но вот синий круг почему-то не округляется и отображается неправильно.

```
        let backgroundCircle = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 140, y: 450), size: CGSize(width: 22, height: 22)))
        backgroundCircle.backgroundColor = .white
        backgroundCircle.layer.cornerRadius = backgroundCircle.frame.height / 2
        backgroundCircle.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
        backgroundCircle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        backgroundCircle.clipsToBounds = true
        mImageView.addSubview(backgroundCircle)

        let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 17, height: 17)))
        circle.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 173/255, blue: 212/255, alpha: 1.0)
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = backgroundCircle.frame.height / 2
        backgroundCircle.addSubview(circle)
      }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сдвиньте базовую точку второго круга на разницу радиусов (2.5)

Comment: @MBo можете по подробнее объяснил, не очень понял где сдвинуть базовую точку круга

Comment: Я вашего языка не знаю, но вижу, что у двух кругов общая верхняя точка описывающего квадрата, а должен быть одинаковый центр. Вероятно, это   `origin:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что у вас неверно задан origin у синего круга. origin – это верхний левый угол, сейчас он совпадает с origin белого круга, а размеры у них разные. Можно исправить, передвинув центр синего круга в центр белого:

```
circle.center = CGPoint(x: backgroundCircle.bounds.width / 2, y: backgroundCircle.bounds.height / 2)
```

Ещё, если так написать, то становится видно, что cornerRadius белого круга слишком велик для синего – края будут обрезаны. Исправить можно, отдельно вычислив cornerRadius для синего круга:

```
circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.bounds.height / 2
```